# Why does routing break down when I modify RouteValueDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I register several routes as such:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "contentPage",
    url: "{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "Index", path = "start" },
    constraints: new { path = new NodeTypeConstraint(siteTree, "contentPage") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "category",
    url: "{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { path = new NodeTypeConstraint(siteTree, "category") }
);
```

And a default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The siteTree is a tree of nodes that can be content pages, categories or products (among other things).

In the constraint I add a new entry to the RouteValueDictionary:

```
public class NodeTypeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly TreeNode _siteTree;
    private readonly string _type;

    public NodeTypeConstraint(TreeNode siteTree, string type)
    {
        _siteTree = siteTree;
        _type = type;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var path = values[parameterName].ToString();
        var node = _siteTree.Find(path);
        if (node != null && node.Properties["type"] == _type)
        {
            values["node"] = node;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Adding "node" to RVD lets me define actions like this one:

```
public class ContentPageController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index(TreeNode node)
     {
         return View(node);
     }
}
```

Without modifying the RVD the action would have to be:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string path) {}
```

...which would force me to once again use the site tree to look up the node. I want to avoid that.

This new helper method lets me generate links:

```
  public static IHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, TreeNode node)
 {
     return html.ActionLink(
         node.Properties["title"] ?? node.Name, 
         "Index", 
         node.Properties["type"], 
         new {path = node}, 
         null);
 }
```

Awsome! But routing breaks down when I do "default" routing. Instead of producing a correct link the following creates a link with an empty "href" attribute:

```
Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")
```

To fix this and without acctually knowing what the hell I'm doing, I changed the default route registration to this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = new FakeConstraint() }
);
```

And this:

```
public class FakeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'd sleep much better if I know why MVC behaves like this. Did I go about this the wrong way?

EDIT: If I throw out that awful FakeConstraint and instead do this, it totally works. If I only knew why, sigh.

```
public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    var path = values[parameterName].ToString();
    var node = _siteTree.Find(path);
    if (node != null && node.Properties["type"] == _type)
    {
        values["node"] = node;

        // These two lines make FakeConstraint redundant:
        values["controller"] = route.Defaults["controller"];
        values["action"] = route.Defaults["action"];

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this "default" root is present in sitetree so first or second root for some reason matches it because _siteTree.Find returns not null?

Comment: But i don't fully understand how this FakeConstraint can resolve it because it will completely ignore default route...

Comment: No it is not present in the sitetree and will not match. And yes, it's very wierd. Asp.Net mvc routing is a wierd beast.